# Xcode 5 Error CertUIFramework.axbundle

Tags: xcode5

I am hoping someone has had these errors and knows how to fix it.
This is the console output in Xcode 5 b4 that suddenly appeared:

> Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888059/cannot-find-executable-for-cfbundle-certuiframework-axbundle/21952086#21952086 try this link

Answer (score 88):

Temporary workaround: click iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings... and run again.

This error message may reappear at random. For me, it happens when I launch a different application. There are [several threads in Apple dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/search.jspa?resultTypes=MESSAGE&peopleEnabled=true&q=CertUIFramework.axbundle) and in StackOverflow about this problem, but none have a definitive answer. This seems to be a SDK error.

Updated: February 10, Xcode 5.1b5.

Comment: Wow, how did you figure this out? Saves me a ton of effort! Thanks.

Comment: SO didn't have a solution, so I went to the Apple dev forums and found it there.

Comment: It will appear again at some point, but good enough until Apple releases another Xcode.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Not downvoting because clearly this works for some people and is therefore helpful, but for the record, I still get the same error on next app launch.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when using the KIF testing framework as imported via CocoaPods. Removing this pod resolved the problem. KIF uses some private frameworks for accessing UI elements so this seems like a reasonable cause

Comment: I had same problem when using KIF

Answer (score 2):

If the reset of the simulator does not solve your problem try the following:

In Terminal type:

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

Delete your "iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk". Then reinstall Xcode. Reinstalling is really fast because just the missing folder gets replaced. This fixed it for me.

Comment: If XCode is installed from the Store, how do you force it to reinstall?

Comment: I did download it again from the developer site.