# Why is this test failing

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubymotion

I am going through a tutorial and it is giving me a failing test, when the code is identical to the code in the tutorial.  I am testing that a button gets tapped, and when it does @was_tapped should equal "true" and it is coming up as "nil"

I am receiving this error:

```
[Tests] $rake spec
================================================================================
A new version of RubyMotion is available. Run `sudo motion update' to upgrade.
================================================================================

     Build ./build/iPhoneSimulator-7.0-Development
   Compile ./spec/main_spec.rb
      Link ./build/iPhoneSimulator-7.0-Development/Tests_spec.app/Tests
    Create ./build/iPhoneSimulator-7.0-Development/Tests_spec.app/PkgInfo
    Create ./build/iPhoneSimulator-7.0-Development/Tests_spec.app/Info.plist
    Create ./build/iPhoneSimulator-7.0-Development/Tests_spec.dSYM
  Simulate ./build/iPhoneSimulator-7.0-Development/Tests_spec.app
2013-12-30 19:43:37.188 Tests[20200:80b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x900b410 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GeoServices.axbundle> (not loaded)
2013-12-30 19:43:37.206 Tests[20200:80b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8ebce90 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
Application 'Tests'
  - has one window

delegate
  - changes variable when button is tapped

2 specifications (2 requirements), 0 failures, 0 errors
```

here is my button controller:

```
class ButtonController < UIViewController
  def viewDidLoad
    super

    @button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
    @button.setTitle("Test me title!", forState:UIControlStateNormal)
    @button.accessibilityLabel = "Test me!"
    @button.sizeToFit
    self.view.addSubview(@button)

    @button.addTarget(self, action:'tapped', forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
  end

  def tapped
    p "I'm tapped!"
    @was_tapped = true
  end
end
```

and here is my main_spec.rb:

```
describe "Application 'Tests'" do
  before do
    @app = UIApplication.sharedApplication
  end

  it "has one window" do
    @app.windows.size.should == 1
  end

  describe "delegate" do
    tests ButtonController

    it "changes variable when button is tapped" do
      tap 'Test me!'
      controller.instance_variable_get("@was_tapped").should == true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: your test seems to be passing as far as I can tell... it says 0 failures, which is also what the tutorial shows. Maybe this will help with the error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036381/xcode-5-error-certuiframework-axbundle?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, I don't see an error here.