# CFBundle 0x8cbaa20

Tags: ios, xcode

Hi I have a new project and now everytime there is an error and I dont know how to fix ist Error: 2014-05-10 00:37:42.300 iDrunkMK2[12442:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8cbaa20  (not loaded)
what should I do? And what does it mean?

Comment: Have you tried a clean? Did you happen to edit your build settings for something?

Comment: no I did nothing. I reinstalled Xcode but the error is there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 5 Error CertUIFramework.axbundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036381/xcode-5-error-certuiframework-axbundle)

Comment: got it :) cleaned the simulator :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find executable for CFBundle CertUIFramework.axbundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888059/cannot-find-executable-for-cfbundle-certuiframework-axbundle)